# Correct way to do a "partial fuzzy" query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I would like to search the description field of a product.

Description field value : "This car has great brakecaliper on the rear".

Match/fuzzy query works when searching for "brakecaliber" or "brakekaliper" or another kind of misspell.

But nothing appears when searching "caliber" or "kaliper".

How would you achieve this?

Comment: Can you show your current search query? And `brakecaliper` is supposed to be in two separate words, how come it's a single word in your description?